# Is there a single website where one can get to know about all upcoming international conferences?

Tags: conference, international

It's very important for a research professional (such as a Statistician) who needs to work on multidisciplinary fields to attend international conferences and see what's going around in the field of research. However, sometimes information contained in the websites about the upcoming conferences are too subject specific (e.g. there's so many related to computer science).

Is there any website that 'gathers information' (rather than just providing information from the user submitted ones) on all conferences irrespective of particular subject areas?

If there is any website about conferences that is related to Statistics and the fields which has its use, it'll do for me as well. Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is [www.conferencealerts.com](http://www.conferencealerts.com). It has conferences listed by categories, including one for mathematics and statistics [here](http://www.conferencealerts.com/#Mathematics%20and%20statistics). You can get periodic alerts in your inbox based on the topics you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

A good website is http://www.wikicfp.com/ (this is the premier outlet for any call for papers that you might need). The best thing about it is that it also comes bundled with a Python API, therefore you might be able with a bit of programming to create your personalized conference schedule by taking into account various factors like: time period, location, field of study, keywords, etc. It contains conferences from all fields, allows you to setup a mail alert, and in general it contains good information about each conference (previous calls, links to their websites, publications, locations, etc).

Another good option, especially if at some point you might look for something else than computing, mathematics, physic is this one: http://www.cfplist.com/ .

Also keep in mind that in any field there are 5 to 10 top publishers. These publishers will also include on their website a list of call for papers. For Mathematics and Statistics on this list you might have SIAM, Springer, Elsevier, IEEE (yes it's a CS outlet but it has a lot of mathematics papers).